# The code in my view controller is running multiple times in Swift playground

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I'm trying to make an app that will just be a background and a button that when pressed will make a second view with another background appear. I got the code for the UIImage from: https://youtu.be/4wodsPzFHQk

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

final class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        let BG = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        BG.image = UIImage(named:"Photo.png")
        BG.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        BG.insertSubview(view, at:0)        
    }    
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

The problem is that when I run the code with the function step through my code I see that the code from `override func loadView()`  to `BG.insertSubview(view, at:0)` is ran multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`loadView()` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview):

> The view controller calls this method when its `view` property is requested but is currently `nil`. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the `view` property.

Since the `loadView` implementation in `MyViewController` never assigns the `view` property, it remains `nil` which means that the next time the `view` property is accessed, `loadView` is called again.

To fix this you would add `self.view = view` at the end of the `loadView` implementation.